# Частично переведено письмо "Восстановление учётной записи" и баг с логотипом

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, восстановление-аккаунта

Не хватает перевода в письме при восстановлении пароля:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же логотип выглядит как-то некачественно: по высоте сплющен.

Answer (score 1):

https://ru.traducir.win/string/10555

Предложил перевод:

> Мы получили запрос на восстановление аккаунта на $SiteName$ для
>   $ToAddress$.

А про логотип, вероятно, нужно на MSE спрашивать.